# rails rspec context in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

In user_spec.rb file I have these same context and I want to recode it with dry method.

```
    context 'when website adress starts with ' do 
      it 'http://, it should validate length of website' do
        @profile.website = "x" * 393 # with appending http to website url its length will be 400.
        assert @profile.save
      end
      it 'http://, it should not validate length of website' do 
        @profile.website = "x" * 394 # with appending http to website url its length will be 401.It should be failed.
        assert !@profile.save
      end
      it 'https://, it should validate length of website' do
        @profile.website = "https://" + "x" * 392 # with appending http to website url its length will be 400.
        assert @profile.save
      end
      it 'https://, it should not validate length of website' do 
        @profile.website = "https://" + "x" * 393 # with appending http to website url its length will be 401.It should be failed.
        assert !@profile.save
      end
    end

  context 'when blog adress starts with ' do 
    it 'http://, it should validate length of blog' do
      @profile.blog = "x" * 393 # with appending http to blog url its length will be 400.
      assert @profile.save
    end
    it 'http://, it should not validate length of blog' do 
      @profile.blog = "x" * 394 # with appending http to blog url its length will be 401.It should be failed.
      assert !@profile.save
    end
    it 'https://, it should validate length of blog' do
      @profile.blog = "https://" + "x" * 392 # with appending http to blog url its length will be 400.
      assert @profile.save
    end
    it 'https://, it should not validate length of blog' do 
      @profile.blog = "https://" + "x" * 393 # with appending http to blog url its length will be 401.It should be failed.
      assert !@profile.save
    end
  end
```

Is there any way to write it like this?I want to use it for 2 methods at the same time.
When I write code below and call `should_validate_length_of('website')` I have  `undefined local variable or method`should_validate_length_of'` error

```
def should_validate_length_of(dummy)
    context 'when website adress starts with ' do 
      it 'http://, it should validate length of website' do
        @profile.dummy = "x" * 393 # with appending http to website url its length will be 400.
        assert @profile.save
      end
      it 'http://, it should not validate length of website' do 
        @profile.dummy = "x" * 394 # with appending http to website url its length will be 401.It should be failed.
        assert !@profile.save
      end
      it 'https://, it should validate length of website' do
        @profile.dummy = "https://" + "x" * 392 # with appending http to website url its length will be 400.
        assert @profile.save
      end
      it 'https://, it should not validate length of website' do 
        @profile.dummy = "https://" + "x" * 393 # with appending http to website url its length will be 401.It should be failed.
        assert !@profile.save
      end
    end
  end
```

Comment: Where are you placing this code?

Comment: Inside of describe block

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this snippet of code where I reduce the amount of code by creating a method

require 'spec_helper'

```
describe SomeClass do
  let(:inner_app) { ->(env){[200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/plain'}, ['All good!']]} }
  let(:app) { SomeClass.new(inner_app) }

  class << self
    def method_tests(m, http_status, response_status)
      it "returns a #{http_status} status"  do
        status, _, _ = app.send(m, response)
        expect(status).to eq(http_status)
      end
      it "has application/json content type headers" do
        _, headers, _ = app.send(m, response)
        expect(headers).to include({'Content-Type' => 'application/json'})
      end
      it "returns a formatted body with status #{response_status}" do
        _, _, body = app.send(m, response)
        expect(body.first).to eq(response.merge!(status: response_status).to_json)
      end
    end
  end

  describe "#success" do
    method_tests(:success, 200, :success)
  end

  describe "#unauthorized" do
    method_tests(:unauthorized, 401, :error)
  end

  describe "#bad_request" do
    method_tests(:bad_request, 400, :error)
  end
end
```

The method itself has to be a class method. Although my tests are different from yours the concept is still the same. :)

Comment: Thank you Leo.class << self is what I was looking for.

Comment: Note that you can actually just prepend the method name with self.some_method and it'll do the same thing